# Where has 150 Vac mains voltage been used?

Tags: mains

Interestingly, on the rear of this instrument from the early 70s, one of the mains input voltage options is 150 Vac (note that all of the remaining ones are not *too* unusual---100 V in Japan; 115 V in the older US; 127 V in some island nations; 220 V in the CIS and mainland Europe; and 240 V in the UK).  Any ideas on where and when such an obscure voltage was used?

[image: rear of instrument]

Comment: It may be that this is just one of the additional ways to connect the primary side of a transformer and they whacked it in just in case.

Answer (score 1):

From what Ive found, some areas in the uk in the early 1900s used 140 - 150V.

This might be of interest: [link](https://www.vintage-radio.net/forum/showthread.php?t=98436)